# Why are HTML tags showing up in my API data?

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, api

I have pulled two APIs into WordPress via JavaScript and XMLHTTPRequest. The data has some HTML tags in the data on the website: https://youaretechy.com/jobs-at-the-muse/ and https://youaretechy.com/jobs-2/

I did research this and I tried adding the following to my JS to remove the HTML tags:

```
function strip_html_tags(str)
{
   if ((str===null) || (str===''))
       return false;
  else
   str = str.toString();
  return str.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
}
```

I tried:

```
var noHTML =  OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

I tried:

```
str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '')
```

Lastly, I tried:

```
  var html = "<p>Some HTML</p>";
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = html;
      var text = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";
```

Unfortunately, none of the code above removed the tags. I have used HTML, CSS and JS in a WordPress Plugin called Shortcoder. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<img src="https://youaretechy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/type_on_PC-300x200.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="200" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-87937" />
  <title>API Testing</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

html {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #696969;
  background: white;
}

#root {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.5rem 2.5rem;
  background-color: #b0bac6;
  margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #696969;
}

p {
  padding: 0 2.5rem 2.5rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  margin: 1rem;
  background: #bobac6;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .2s linear;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 8px 45px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  transform: translate3D(0, -2px, 0);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .card {
    flex: 1 1 calc(50% - 2rem);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .card {
    flex: 1 1 calc(33% - 2rem);
  }
}

.card:nth-child(2n) h1 {
  background-color: #b0bac6;
  color: #696969;
}

.card:nth-child(4n) h1 {
  background-color: #b0bac6;
  color: #696969;
}

.card:nth-child(5n) h1 {
  background-color #b0bac6;
  color: #696969;
}


  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="root"></div>


<script>
'use strict';
const app = document.getElementById('root');

const container = document.createElement('div');
container.setAttribute('class', 'container');

app.appendChild(container);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?markdown=true&page=1', true);
request.onload = function () {

   var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach(job => {
      const card = document.createElement('div');
      card.setAttribute('class', 'card');

     function strip_html_tags(str)
       {
         if ((str===null) || (str===''))
       return false;
         else
        str = str.toString();
        return str.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
        }


      const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
      h1.textContent = job.title;

      const p = document.createElement('p');
      job.description = job.description.substring(0, 300);
      p.textContent = `${job.description}...`;

      container.appendChild(card);
      card.appendChild(h1);
      card.appendChild(p);


   });

  } else {
    const errorMessage = document.createElement('marquee');
    errorMessage.textContent = `Gah, it's not working!`;
    app.appendChild(errorMessage);

  }
}

request.send();

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance!!

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new temporary element and assign that html to it, you can then extract the `textContent` which will automatically remove all the HTML tags.

```js
const data = '<p>McLean 1 (19050), United States of America, McLean, Virginia<br><br>At Capital One, we\'re building a leading information-based technology company. Still founder-led by Chairman and Chief Executive Officer Richard Fairbank, Capital One is on a mission to help our customers succeed by bringing ingenuity, simplicity, and humanity to banking. We measure our efforts by the success our customers enjoy and the advocacy they exhibit. We are succeeding because they are succeeding. <br><br>Guided by our shared val…ifications: </u></b><br>Bachelor\'s Degree or Military experience<br>At least 2 years of experience in analysis<br><br><b><u>Preferred Qualifications: </u></b><br>Master\'s Degree<br><br>At least 5 years of experience in analysis<br>At least years of experience in financial services<br>At least 1 year of experience in consulting<br>At least 2 years of experience in people management<br><br><b>Capital One will consider sponsoring a new qualified applicant for employment authorization for this position</b></p>';

const temp = document.createElement('p');
temp.innerHTML = data;
document.getElementById('out').textContent = temp.textContent;
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This might seem obvious, but I am a newb. I made const data='textContent' but that did not work. What should const data equal?

Comment: Your site is hitting the endpoint https://www.themuse.com/api/public/jobs?&page=1 which has a results array of objects each with a content property containing HTML so I assume it's that. The github endpoint in your question has no HTML.

Comment: When I added the code above, all my API data disappeared. Any ideas?